# Xampp php_zmq.dll Unable to load

Tags: php, apache, dll, xampp

i know this question has been asked before but, i can't solve my problem.

my php version is `PHP Version 7.0.13`

the Architecture is `x86`

and my apache version is `Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.13`

i try to install the zmq with composer and here is the composer require part

`"react/zmq": "0.2.*|0.3.*"`

how ever i got this message

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_zmq.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
>    in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_zmq.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
>    in Unknown on line 0

https://pecl.php.net/package/zmq/1.1.3/windows

i try to install all pacakage that available in that link, than copy the `php_zmq.dll` and  `libzmq.dll` to the part where they should, and i already write the extension to in my php.ini

`[ZMQ]
extension=php_zmq.dll`

but all i always get that following error. Someone can help me what should i do?

thank you

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/zmq/1.1.3/php_zmq-1.1.3-7.0-nts-vc14-x86.zip) or [this](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/zmq/1.1.3/php_zmq-1.1.3-7.0-ts-vc14-x86.zip)?

Comment: ya i already try that @RendyEkoPrastiyo